# Trigger CSS animation when hovering over pseudo element?

Tags: css

I am attempting to trigger CSS animations when a pseudo element is hovered.

I currently have 2 videos that show depending which 50% side of the browser the mouse is hovering and I want to apply a similar effect to animate some text.

I want the `<p>` tag to move up and fade in while moving the `<h1>` tag up at the same time and in the same way, like this website:

https://seedlipdrinks.com/uk/

Here's the kind of structure I'm working with for my `<p>` and `<h1>` tags:

```
<div class="caption_overlay">
    <div class="caption_grid">
      <div class="live_caption">

        <h1>A mix of apartments and terrace homes</h1>

        <a href="#"><p>Explore</p></a>

        </div>

        <div class="eat_caption">

        <h1>A brand new public eat street</h1>

        <a href="#"><p>Explore</p></a>

      </div>

    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

Current code for videos

```
.video_hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.video_hover::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  height:100%; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index:100;
}

.video_hover video {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.live_video:hover video {
  opacity:0;
} 

.live_video::before {
  right: 0;
}

.live_video:hover + .eat_video video {
  opacity:1; 
} 

.eat_video video {
  opacity:0;
} 

.eat_video::before {
  left: 0;
}
```

Example of code for text animation. I want the h1 and p tags to begin with padding-top: 100px; and remove or add padding depending on whether mouse is hovering left or right side of the screen like the website I referenced

```
.live_caption h1:hover, .eat_caption h1:hover {
  padding-top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
}

.live_caption p:hover, .eat_caption p:hover  {
  padding-top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS-only approach can be achieved by nesting the caption markup (ie your `<h1>` and `<p>` tags) with the corresponding video elements [in your existing page structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57881965/how-to-hide-video-on-div-hover):

```
<div class="live_video video_hover">
  <video muted class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
 </video>

 <!-- Nest caption block with live_video video block -->
 <div class="caption">
   <h1>A mix of apartments and terrace homes</h1>
   <a href="#">
     <p>Explore</p>
   </a>
 </div>

</div>
```

By doing this, you can then specify CSS that modifies the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property of the newly introduced `.caption` element (of each video) so that the "y translation" of respective captions are toggled between `0%` and `100%`, depending on the user interaction.

To achieve a smooth animated effect when those captions are translated, the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property is applied to the `transform` property:

```
transition: transform ease-in-out 0.5s
```

Doing this causes the caption to smoothly animate between differenet transforms when the transform value changes.

In code, this solution can be implemented as:

```css
.video_hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add this */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video_hover video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video_hover::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.live_video::before {
  left: 0;
}

.eat_video::before {
  right: 0;
}

.eat_video video {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.live_video:hover video {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.live_video:hover+.eat_video video {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* New CSS begins */


/* Define common styling for caption blocks of either video */

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 150;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.5s;
  background: pink;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Live video caption visible by default (out of view) */

.live_video .caption {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}


/* Eat video caption hidden by default (out of view) */

.eat_video .caption {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}


/* Animate eat video caption into view when hovering the pesudo element */

.live_video:hover .caption {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}


/* Animate live video caption out of view when hovering the pesudo element */

.eat_video:hover .caption {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="live_video video_hover">
  <video muted class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
 </video>
  <!-- Nest caption block with corresponding video to display with -->
  <div class="caption">
    <h1>A mix of apartments and terrace homes</h1>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Explore</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="eat_video video_hover">
  <video muted class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://www.fbdemo.com/video/video/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
 </video>
  <!-- Nest caption block with corresponding video to display with -->
  <div class="caption">
    <h1>A brand new public eat street</h1>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Explore</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very last thing.. how would I make it so both captions are out of view by default to begin with?

Comment: I'm also having issues with creating a height for the caption class and having the overflow hidden when transform: translateY (0%) I want to keep the overflow hidden but it is currently pushing the rest of the content upwards if that makes sense

Comment: @BurgerSasha you would like them to be out of view initally, when cursor is away from browser, then left caption in view if hover left side and right caption in view if hover right side?

Comment: @BurgerSasha sorry about the overflow issue - just updated answer, hope that helps

Comment: Yes that would great! Thank you, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Yes, perfect! You are a legend

Comment: Haha no worries :)